# R data.table control number of printed digits

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to reduce the number of digits printed when calling a data.table object in R. I'd rather fit more columns into the console than seeing up to 8 decimal points for each number.

The standard way, `options("digits" = 4)` (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r)), does not seem to work with data tables.

An example:

```
 set.seed(7)
 DT <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = 1:10)
 DT # prints 10 digits for me, including the decimal point

 options("digits" = 4)
 DT # prints 8 digits (?)
```

Generally, though, `option` works, since

```
 set.seed(7)
 rnorm(1)
```

prints `2.287`

Comment: No repro. It prints four on my console. Maybe you're using Rstudio.

Comment: It also prints 4 digits in my RStudio. Did you restart your session?

Comment: I'm using R.app on mac

Comment: I'm getting 4 digits in RStudio on Windows. Looks like an R.app issue. :-(

Comment: I restarted my session. It now prints 4 digits after the comma instead of 4 digits total.

Comment: Try `print(DT, digits = 4)`

Comment: Same result as before (4 digits after comma, not the 8 digits I had before for some reason). [Here's a screenshot just in case](http://i.imgur.com/ZioYX6K.png). I guess this is an R.app issue :-/ Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hmm that's strange. I have `format(runif(5), digits = 4)` returning 5 digits after the decimal, but all other values of `digits` behaving as expected.

Comment: Try `print(DT, nsmall = 4)`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25860518/1191259 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3443687/1191259 (credit due to @Frank)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this behavior.
Here is the output of my console:

```
set.seed(7)
DT <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = 1:10)
DT

           x  y
1:  2.28724716134  1
2: -1.19677168222  2
3: -0.69429251044  3
4: -0.41229295114  4
5: -0.97067334112  5
6: -0.94727994523  6
7:  0.74813934029  7
8: -0.11695522589  8
9:  0.15265762628  9
10: 2.18997810733 10
```

However:

```
options("digits" = 4)

DT
      x  y
 1:  2.2872  1
 2: -1.1968  2
 3: -0.6943  3
 4: -0.4123  4
 5: -0.9707  5
 6: -0.9473  6
 7:  0.7481  7
 8: -0.1170  8
 9:  0.1527  9
 10: 2.1900 10
```

Note also that `print.data.table` has an ellipsis argument `...` which is passed on to `format`, so for a single use case you can pass `digits` along like so:

```
print.data.table(DT, digits=4)
```

See `?format` for additional options when printing a `data.table`.